# Delphi find specific cause for Exception

Tags: mysql, delphi, exception, delphi-2010

I am having a Database connected application.
Connected using BDE components and database is MySQL.

Now I am doing some validations for checking if duplicate entry while insert statement is executed.

The following is the code to check if duplicate entry for primary key attribute .

```
var
  error :string; 
  cmpres:integer;
begin
 ...
 /* all my data queries */
  try
    Query1.ExecSQL;
  Except
   on E: Exception do
   /*check if its a Duplicate entry or other exception*/
    begin    
         error := E.Message;
         error := copy(error,length(error)-16,length(error)-2);
         cmpres :=CompareStr(LowerCase(error),'for key '+#39+'primary'+#39) ;
         if cmpres = 0  then
           MessageDlg('Entry already exist',mtError,[mbok],0)
         else
           MessageDlg('Invalid Data Entries',mtError,[mbok],0);
         exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The database exceptions are broadly put inside  `EDatabaseError`

Can anyone tell me is there any way I can differentiate between these errors without doing the Message comparisons.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the debugger tell you?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The Debugger is giving me this error message `error 'Key violation.'#$D#$A'[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld-5.5.11]Duplicate entry ''64'' for key ''PRIMARY''''`

Comment: No, I mean what **class** is the error, and what properties does that class offer you.

Comment: `TQuery` has the `OnPostError` event where you **should** catch the exceptions. I know someone here suggested this error message text comparing, but it's wrong way to do this. I can't imagine if someone will translate these messages. Take a look e.g. on [`this article`](http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa103001a.htm), it's not only ADO related, you can modify the technique to BDE as well.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan its `EDatabaseError` ,and it has nothing inside it

Comment: @Shirish11 Read the article. It's full of code.

Comment: @TLama, I know the post you're referring to, and I did **not** recommend comparing error message text. (In fact, the opposite - I posted a code comment suggesting (and demonstrating) using `ErrorCode` **instead** of comparing text.) :)

Comment: @Ken, oh, now I can see, it's hidden in the comment. Next time I'll pay attention to read the comments as well, not just think they are describing the code beside, sorry for that :-)

Comment: @Tlama, no problem. I say enough stupid things that I don't like being blamed for things I didn't say. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using BDE, the exceptions should be EDBEngineError, not EDatabaseError. You can do this:

```
try
    Query1.ExecSQL;
except
    on E: EDBEngineError do
    begin
        for i := 0 to E.ErrorCount - 1 do
        begin
            err := E.Errors[i];
            case err.ErrorCode of
                ... stuff ...
            end;
        end
    end;
end
```

Comment: is this applicable for other DB components and Databases?

Comment: Looks like it. You should be able to check pretty easily by doing (if E is EDBEngineError) then ...